# aws amplify datastore syncing the whole database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

In my DynamoDb I have about 200k datapoints, there will be more in the future. When I logout my local datastorage gets cleared. When I log in, datastore starts to sync it with the cloud. The problem is that the syncing is taking really long for over 200k datapoints. The datapoints are sensorik data that its displayed on a chart.

My idea is to fetch only the data directly from the database which I need without bloating up my entire local storage.

Is there a way to fetch the data what I need without saving it into the offline storage? I was thinking to rather use AWS timeseries for my chart data.

Comment: Which language are you using for your client?

Answer (score 1):

SyncExpression Configuration is required for fetch the specific data based on your need.

DOC: [https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/js/](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/js/#clear-local-data)

```js
import { DataStore, syncExpression } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Post, Comment } from './models';

DataStore.configure({
  syncExpressions: [
    syncExpression(Post, () => {
      return post => post.rating.gt(5);
    }),
    syncExpression(Comment, () => {
      return comment => comment.status.eq('active');
    }),
  ]
});
```